# Redirecting a lot of pages via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I currently have these pages:

```
http://example.com/category/page/123/test-test
http://example.com/category/page/2563/test2-test
http://example.com/category/page/2853/test2-test
```

I want to 301 redirect them to this:

```
http://example.com/page/123/test-test
http://example.com/page/2563/test2-test
http://example.com/page/2853/test2-test
```

How can I redirect all of my pages without processing them one by one?

I have a few lines below as well:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

#this is where I plan to put my rewrite text

RewriteRule ^(system) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoud use mod rewrite for this purpose

something like this should do it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(system) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^/category/page/(\d+)/(.*)$ /page/$1/$2 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

you can review the documention of [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: ok that is weird. I believe your answer would've worked. It doesn't.

Comment: Remove the L from `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]` or remove the L from my answer.

Comment: added more of the htaccess above. removeing the L from your answer doesn't work either.

Comment: @Thorpe: the order of the rule does matter so please see my edit ;-)

Comment: That didn't go well. I now have a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Thrope: if you take one of the rule the 500 error disaspear what your error log are saying?

Comment: This answer should be working. I'll work on it with your code.